# SQL DELETE from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, join

When  I try to execute this delete query, SQL gives me this error:

"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`carpooling`.`pedido`, CONSTRAINT `pedido_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_ROTA`) REFERENCES `rota` (`ID_ROTA`))"

**Query:**

```
DELETE rota,rota_alerta,pedido FROM rota
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pedido ON rota.ID_ROTA=pedido.ID_ROTA
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rota_alerta ON rota.ID_ROTA=rota_alerta.ID_ROTA
    WHERE rota.ID_UTILIZADOR=26;
```

I'm trying to delete all rows from "pedido" and "rota_alerta" that are linked to a row of table "rota" by "ID_ROTA". This "ID_ROTA" depends from the number of rows that have the same "ID_UTILIZADOR" (in this case, 26) on table "rota".

Also, I want to delete all rows of "rota" that have the specified "ID_UTILIZADOR".

How could I fix this?

**EDIT**

I forgot to say that I don't want to use "cascade constraints" because there are cases where I should do a "delete rota where ID_UTILIZADOR=26" (as mentioned in a comment) and avoid to delete the child rows if they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'd delete my child collections first:

```
delete rota_alerta where rota_id in(select id_rota from rota where ID_UTILIZADOR=26)
delete pedido where rota_id in(select rota_id from rota where ID_UTILIZADOR=26)
delete rota where ID_UTILIZADOR=26
```

Comment: @CristianoSantos this is essentially hand-coding a cascading delete and will give you the same issues as described in your comment

Comment: @Pleun But in the other query where I should not delete the child rows, I just need to execute something like "delete rota where ID_UTILIZADOR=26"

Comment: Yes, you got a point there. Will cause your delete (in the other query) to fail in some cases but if that is what you want this solution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Change your foreign key constraint to `CASCADE`

Well, from the comment you gave it now has become clear that the cascading delete is conditional.

This means you either need to code out the exact conditions. Either in your client or in a stored procedure.

Or still change to cascade and add triggers again to prevent the deletion (not sure if that is possible in MySql)

Comment: Due to security risks, I can't do it =S.

Comment: In some cases, I do not want to give the permission of deleting rows from "rota" if childs rows exist and this query should not pass.

Comment: You cannot have your cake and eat it too. This is by the way something that is quite essential in your question. You should update the question. Also I would not consider this  a security risk but a functional constraint.

Comment: As your answer are helpfull for some others, I will upvote it too =)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `cascade constraints` clause